# getting error while using map function with hooks in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a simple COVID tracker app, but after fetching data when I use the map function I receive the following error:

```
Error : TypeError:countryData.map is not a function
```

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

export const CountriesData = () => {
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries';

  useEffect(() => {
    async function DataOfCountry() {
      const data2 = await fetch(url);
      const MainData2 = await data2.json();
      console.log(MainData2);
      setCountryData(MainData2);
      setLoading(true);
    }
    DataOfCountry();
  }, [setCountryData]);

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <NativeSelect>
        <option value="global"> Global</option>

        {countryData.map((country, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={country}>
            {country}{' '}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `MainData2`? It's probably not an array, but an object.

Comment: looks like your base URL is incorrect, it should be 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/' . As you are appending countries on fetch call.

Comment: Dear Brother @Sam Url is working fine . facing issue on Maping call

Comment: Dear brother @ZsoltMeszaros I made slightly changes and yes its not Array but an Object ..kindly help me how to convert object to Array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the returned data is an object, not an array. You don't need to convert it; the fetched data's `countries` property is an array of countries, so you need to update your state with that:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

export const CountriesData = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries';

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCountries() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      // you should handle errors!

      setCountries(data.countries);
      setLoading(true);
    }
    fetchCountries();
  }, [setCountries]);

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <NativeSelect>
        <option value="global">Global</option>
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <option key={country.iso3} value={country.name}>
            {country.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```